# pass data between slot and component vuejs

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, vuejs2

hi im using vuejs2 and laravel in project 
what im asking is it possible to pass data from slot to component 
like this

```
 Vue.component('search_and_select',{
    template:
    '<div>'+
        <slot name='Slot_name'></slot>
    '</div>',
    data:function(){
        return {
            this_is_test_data:null,
            custom_method_here:null,
            custom_model :null
        }
    },
    methods:{
        custom_method_here:function()
        {
            // code here
        }
    },
    props:{}
});
```

and this is the html code

```
<div is='search_and_select' >
    <div slot='Slot_name'>
    <!-- 
       is is possible to write code here like this   
       <input type='text' @keyup='custom_method()' v-model='custom_model' />
     -->
    </div>
</div>
```

can i do this code also if not can anyone help me how to do something like this ..

Comment: it's not clear where you're defining `custom_method` and `custom_model`

Comment: they are inside the component methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### That's what `slot-scope` is for

in your code, it would look something like this...

```js
Vue.component('search_and_select',{
    template:
    '<div>'+
        <slot name='Slot_name'></slot>
    '</div>',
    data:function(){
        return {
            this_is_test_data:null,
            custom_method:null,
            custom_model:null
        }
    },
    methods:{
        custom_method:function()
        {
            // code here
        }
    },
    props:{}
});
```

and this is the html code

```
<div is='search_and_select' >
    <div slot='Slot_name' slot-scope="{ custom_method, custom_model}">
       <input type='text' @keyup='custom_method()' v-model='custom_model' />
    </div>
</div>
```